# Wrong region for accumulation of fat

Tags: nutrition, diet, mental-health, body-fat

I am a female in my mid 20. I am 5 ft(sadly, very short about which I do feel insecure all the time) with a weight of 48 kg approx. Now as you can imagine, I am very thin.
 Infact my collar bones are so clearly visible that my mum often think that i am suffering from malnutrition. Somehow most of the fat in accumulating near thigh and belly region, but not where it should be like hands(I have skeletal hands) and near the collar(collar bones give a skeletal effect). 

Is there anything I can do to avoid accumulation of fat in the wrong region and make it accumulate in the right region. Also I have heard that fat accumulation near the lower body area might lead to gynecological problems.
 Tell me what should I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is only so little you can do about the fat accumulation. These things are work of natural evolution and genetics.

From the *Female body shape* article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female_body_shape):

> Estrogens cause higher levels of fat to be stored in a female body than in a male body. They also affect body fat distribution, causing fat to be stored in the buttocks, thighs, and hips in women, but generally not around their waists, which will remain about the same size as they were before puberty

So the problem you are having is a matter of female hormones and associated genetic, which cannot be altered.

Due to the same facts, the issue is different in males:

> Android fat distribution describes the distribution of human adipose tissue mainly around the trunk and upper body, in areas such as the abdomen, chest, shoulder and nape of neck. This pattern may lead to an "apple-shaped" or central obesity, and is more common in males than in females. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_fat_distribution)

My most sincere "answer" to you is that you start doing some weight lifting. Focus on the whole body. With appropriate training, your buttocks and thighs will become firmer. When working on your whole upper torso (back + arms) your skeletal muscle will become also firmer which will have on huge influence on your looks. Moreover, with weight lifting and general fitness exercise your posture will become better, also affecting on your looks. Moreover, will intensive enough training you´ll lose fat from the same region it has been accumulating.

Comment: Re: Your last sentence. Fat loss in the body works on the LIFO (Last In, First Out) order, so if the region in question was the first accumulation point, it will be the last to come off. I will work on finding references, this is from classes for my kinesiology degree.